# Core Java and JVM Security Preventing Code Injection

Tags: java, jvm

I recall learning in computer organization class that in c and computer organization class that blocks of text in code can be changed and that it is potentially a large security hole. 
Now that I am coding in Java, I would like to know, what prevents injection of byte-code to the JVM and what security measures are in place so that data is not manipulated at run time in the RAM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code injection is not prevented, instead code is prevented from bypassing the security manager, injected or not.

You don't have access to raw memory (unless your SecurityManager lets you get access to Unsafe), so you can't mess with internals in pure Java.